# Django: Invalid block tag: 'score_for_object', expected 'empty' o 'endfor'

Tags: python, django, django-voting

im trying new to django, im using django 1.6. I am trying to use django-voting as explained in the tutorial: http://www.justinlilly.com/python/django_voting.html

i get a error message when i request my template:

Invalid block tag: 'score_for_object', expected 'empty' o 'endfor'

my template looks like:

```
{% score_for_object object as score %}
                <h5>Votes <span id="score">{{ score.score }}</span> point{{ score.score|pluralize }}
                     after <span id="num_votes">{{ score.num_votes }}</span> vote{{ score.num_votes|pluralize }}</h5>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="vote('{{ object.slug }}', 'up');">I like it!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="vote('{{ object.slug }}', 'down');">I hate it!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="vote('{{ object.slug }}', 'clear');">I take it back! Clear my vote.</a></li>
            </ul>
                {% endscore_for_object object %}
```

I've tried  without {% endscore_for_object object %} and i get the same error message
my urls:

```
tip_dict = {
    'model': Promo,
    'template_object_name': 'promos',
    'slug_field': 'slug',
    'allow_xmlhttprequest': 'true',
}
urlpatterns += patterns('',
   url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)vote/?$', vote_on_object,             tip_dict, name="tip-voting"),
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to load the template tag with somethinhg like

```
{% load voting_tags %}
```

at the beginning of your html file, see: [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#load) and [django-voting doc](https://code.google.com/p/django-voting/wiki/RedditStyleVoting#Template)